# read __consumer_offsets with kafka go

Tags: go, apache-kafka

I want to read from the topic __consumer_offsets using this library: https://github.com/segmentio/kafka-go

My problem is that unless I specify a partition nothing seems to happen. There are 100 partitions for this topic by default, it seems unreasonable to query kafka for the list of partitions and then loop over them to read them, and I'm hoping for a pre-existing method in the library that reads messages from all partitions in the topic.

Currently the following works, after I verified with kafkacat that there are messages in partition 15 of __consumer_offsets topic:

```golang
  r := kafka.NewReader(kafka.ReaderConfig{
    Brokers:   []string{"kafka:9092"},
    Topic:     "__consumer_offsets",
    Partition: 15
  })
  r.SetOffset(0)

  for {
    m, err := r.ReadMessage(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
      log.Println("Error while trying to read message")
      log.Fatal(err)
      break
    }
    log.Printf("message at offset %d\n", m.Offset)
  }

  r.Close()
```

I would imagine that partition choosing should be transparent on the user level unless needed. Am I wrong?

Is there a way to read from the topic regardless of which partitions the messages are in? or to rephrase, read from all partitions?

Answer (score 0):

Use the consumer group API, and you don't need to give partitions.

https://github.com/segmentio/kafka-go#consumer-groups

> ```
> // GroupID holds the optional consumer group id.  If GroupID is specified, then
> // Partition should NOT be specified e.g. 0
> GroupID string
>
>
> // Partition to read messages from.  Either Partition or GroupID may
> // be assigned, but not both
> Partition int
> ```

https://godoc.org/github.com/segmentio/kafka-go#ReaderConfig

Comment: I don't understand your answer. I don't want to consume messages from a topic with a group id, I want to read the offsets of all the groups from __consumer_offsets. The part of the documentation you pointed me at explicitly says it will return -1 when using a group id. Plus, commiting offsets will defeat the entire purpose

Comment: Your question was asking how to not give a partition number. If you read the configuration docs of that library, you either give a single partition, or a consumer groupId so that all partitions are consumed. That property doesn't control what you read within the topic itself.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, it might be that I don't yet understand kafka 100%. What is the logic in implementing a mechanism that does not allow me to read the entire topic unless I use a group id? I can do it without one when using kafkacat so why not in go? In my case, I want to read the `__consumer_offsets` topic because I want to do something with them (without changing them), so using a group and committing offsets defeats the purpose entirely.  Is there a reason it was implemented this way?

Comment: another thing, I just tried what you suggested, it creates an infinite loop of reading __consumer_offsets, automatically committing a new offset, and reading the offsets that were just committed

Comment: The mechanism is called "consumer groups". Kafkacat (and console-consumer) form a random one for you. You would have to turn off auto-commits if you want to read that topic without an infinite loop. I don't know the non-Java properties for that, though